# Chrome is blocking third party cookies; asking me to set Same Site attribute = None and Secure, but does not specify how or where?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, leaflet

This is the message I am getting using a Leaflet.js heatmap, and I can't see my circle markers, and I believe this is most likely the issue.

> Because a cookie’s SameSite attribute was not set or is invalid, it defaults to SameSite=Lax, which prevents the cookie from being sent in a cross-site request. This behavior protects user data from accidentally leaking to third parties and cross-site request forgery.
> Resolve this issue by updating the attributes of the cookie:
> Specify SameSite=None and Secure if the cookie should be sent in cross-site requests. This enables third-party use.
> Specify SameSite=Strict or SameSite=Lax if the cookie should not be sent in cross-site requests.

I am using Javascript, and the video from Chrome said to do:

Set-Cookie: cname=cvalue; SameSite = None; Secure

But where do I do this?

Comment: When you set cookies, you can set attributes that the browser will read, such as `Expires` or `Max-Age` (`Cookie: a=b; Expires=Wed, 21 Oct 2021 07:28:00 GMT`). `Same-Site` and `Secure` are such attributes. So if you're setting cookies, be that on the server-side or from JS, you'll have to add `; SameSite=None; Secure` at the end.

Comment: So I put (Cookie: a=b; Expires=Wed, 21 Oct 2021 07:28:00 GMT; SameSite=None; Secure) at the top of my JS file? What specifically do I put? Sorry for my ignorance lol

Comment: If you're using cookies, you must be either setting `document.cookie` on your javascript, or you must have some server-side code (PHP, Node.js, Flask, Django, etc) that adds a `Set-Cookie` header. The value of `document.cookie` or of the `Set-Cookie` header is what you have to change.

Comment: I'm not using document.cookie, because I have no clue what that is. I'm sending http requests via MapBox API that are getting blocked, so assuming it would be document.cookie, which I have not specified in my JS document, what would I do?
I need literal code haha

Comment: This is probably not your fault, since that's something the MapBox API would have to change. The requirement for cookies to be marked either `SameSite=None` or `Secure` is a recent change in all browsers, needed because anything else would have a high risk of exposing your cookies (and so your login sessions) to someone who shouldn't have them. That said, make sure you're calling that API over HTTPS, rather than HTTP

Comment: Okay Thank you for explaining that. I had a feeling it may have been something out of my control.

Comment: You mean you get your heatmap / data from mapbox?

Answer (score 0):

```
// set cookie
app.get("/set-cookie", (req, res) => {
  res.header("Set-Cookie", `username="john doe"; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None;`);
  res.status(200).json({ message: "Cookie has been set" });
});

// clear cookie
app.get("/clear-cookie", (req, res) => {
  res.clearCookie("username");
  res.status(200).json({ message: "Cookie has been cleared" });
});
```